# What is the best way to hide "Completed or Cancelled Items" in a table?

Tags: google-app-maker

So I have setup a model/table that users will use as a project task list. I would like it so that when they change the Status (a field in the model) of an item to either Completed or Cancelled it is hidden.

That way they are only dealing with active entries. But I would also like them to be able to view these hidden (archived) items if needed.

I added the following code to the onAttach option of the table

```
var datasource = app.datasources.Projects;
 datasource.query.filters.Status._notContains = 'Completed';
 datasource.load();
```

And then I have a button with the following code so they can see hidden/archived items:

```
widget.datasource.query.clearFilters();
widget.datasource.load();
app.closeDialog();
var datasource = app.datasources.Projects;
 datasource.query.filters.Status._contains = 'Completed';
 datasource.load();
```

It works, but I feel like there might be a better/more elegant way to accomplish this. Especially since it looks like the app has to load then data, THEN filter it (which results in a slower load). (I think I might have some redundant code in there as well)

Also I feel like I am missing something with my syntax, because I can't get it to filter out Completed AND Cancelled.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single page of items in the table and there aren't many items, then you can filter on the client side. For example, you can use a binding expression to add a "projectHidden" style to the row based on some logic and then use CSS to change the visibility of the row.

For your second code block, there is no reason to clear filters, load, set the filters and then load again. Just clear the filters, set the new filter, and call load. Also if you are manually controlling the query load, then you might want to uncheck the setting in the data source to automatically load data.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var datasource = app.datasources.Projects;
 datasource.query.filters.Status._notEquals = 'Completed';
 datasource.query.filters.Status._notEquals = 'Cancelled';
 datasource.load();
```

Comment: That format didn't seem to work for me, but I was able to get it to work using the _notContains option [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405004/how-can-i-filter-multiple-variables-in-a-table?noredirect=1#comment72055994_42405004)