# How Can I Filter Multiple Variables In A Table?

Tags: google-app-maker

How can I use the query/filter function to filter out two categories of the same field.

Example which currently works to filter "Completed" task:

```
var datasource = app.datasources.Project;
 datasource.query.filters.Status._notContains = 'Completed';
 datasource.load();
```

But I would like to have it filter both "Completed" AND "Canceled" tasks.

I tried these, but they didn't seem to work:

Example 1

```
 var datasource = app.datasources.Project;
     datasource.query.filters.Status._notContains = 'Completed';
     datasource.query.filters.Status._notContains = 'Canceled';
     datasource.load();
```

Example 2

```
var datasource = app.datasources.Project;
     datasource.query.filters.Status._notContains = 'Completed', 'Canceled';
     datasource.load();
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I believe your Example 1 would work with the _notEquals operator instead of _notContains

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this, instead of using `_notContains`, please use `_notIn` the following way:

```
var datasource = app.datasources.Project;
var statuses = ['Completed', 'Canceled'];
     datasource.query.filters.Status._notIn = statuses;
     datasource.load();
```

Please refer to the **[official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_datasources)** for a better and more detailed explanation. I hope this helps!