# About Filter Lists of Google App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Where do I create a filter script on the list of table in first time.
I tried in onLoad event but its not move([How Can I Filter Multiple Variables In A Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42405004/how-can-i-filter-multiple-variables-in-a-table?rq=1)).

```
var datasource = app.datasources.Project;
var statuses = ['Completed', 'Canceled'];
     datasource.query.filters.Status._notIn = statuses;
     datasource.load();
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnAttach since you are modifying the datasource and there is no point in loading it twice and waiting for it. I am guessing you are using onDataLoad since there is no onLoad event that I am aware of.

> This script will run on the client when the widget is attached to the
>   DOM. The widget can be referenced using parameter widget. Common uses
>   for the onAttach event on a page are reading a browser cookie or
>   initializing a datasource query from window URL parameters.

Use

`widget.datasource.query.filters.`...